# How to make skype use less data?

Tags: skype, ubuntu-11.10

I'm currently travelling and using Skype to stay in touch with family. I am also using an Internet plan with limited data and Skype is taking a lot of data from that plan. From my provider history, I can see that it use around 9Mo every minute of Skype calls (with video).

I'm looking for a way to decrease the data usage of my Skype session. I couldn't find anything related to data usage in the Skype options. I was thinking maybe a way of reducing video and/or sound quality or throttling the bandwith used by Skype.

If what it takes is simply to stop using video (incoming and outgoing), I will do that, but I'd rather first know what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that avoiding video calls is the only way you can reduce skype's data transfer

Answer (score 1):

Skype consumes a ton of bandwidth with video calls, no way around that. If you turn off your side of the webcam, it will use less data. Skype video calls are like streaming video - it takes a lot.

Voice calls don't take nearly a third as much though, and should suffice for calling.

You can also downgrade to Skype 4.2, which does not have the Facebook stuff that takes a good chunk of CPU and bandwidth from what I can see. You can get it from [Filehippo.](http://www.filehippo.com/download_skype/8287/)

Answer (score 0):

There are no [magic options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqb27.png). If you want Skype to use less data, **you** have to use less data.

The video data is most likely 95% of all the bandwidth Skype uses (if not more). The *overhead* produced by Skype is most likely neglectable.

But please keep in mind, [Skype is a P2P application](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10983/What-are-P2P-communications), so it is possible (to my understanding) that it will consume bandwidth with actions unrelated to your own usage.